# How do I make apt-get install less noisy?

Tags: apt

If I use `apt-get install -qq mono-devel`, I expect it to be quiet except for errors, according to the help:

```
-qq No output except for errors
```

Instead I get:

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Selecting previously unselected package binfmt-support.
(Reading database ... 84711 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking binfmt-support (from .../binfmt-support_2.0.8_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cli-common.
Unpacking cli-common (from .../cli-common_0.8.2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgdiplus.
Unpacking libgdiplus (from .../libgdiplus_2.10-3_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmono-2.0-1.
Unpacking libmono-2.0-1 (from .../libmono-2.0-1_2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmono-2.0-dev.
Unpacking libmono-2.0-dev (from .../libmono-2.0-dev_2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmono-corlib4.0-cil.
Unpacking libmono-corlib4.0-cil (from .../libmono-corlib4.0-cil_2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmono-system-xml4.0-cil.
Unpacking libmono-system-xml4.0-cil (from .../libmono-system-xml4.
```

and *more*...

In fact, a couple hundred lines worth of output. This does not appear to match up with `no output except for errors`.

How do I actually get `apt-get install` to print out *only* when there are errors keeping it from installing?

Comment: Have you tried using -q=# where # is a quiet level? (It's in the manual.) You may want to raise a bug report against this.

Comment: @PaddyLandau I did indeed. I don't know why it's talking about selecting previously unselected package either or why that would be important, and I'm not sure if it's related to the state of the vms I'm running this on these on either, [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/). But the answer worked well.

Comment: "Selecting previously unselected package" simply means that the package manager is including a package required to satisfy dependencies. As I previously wrote, you may want to raise a bug report about the `--quiet` option appearing not to be working correctly.

Comment: I'm unhappy to report that same symptom in Ubuntu 15.04 20150709.

Comment: Looks like this relates to 2009 dpkg issue report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=539617 .

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/227190/how-do-i-ask-apt-get-to-skip-any-interactive-post-install-configuration-steps

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The man page for apt-get is as follows:

```
NAME
       apt-get - APT package handling utility -- command-line interface

SYNOPSIS
       apt-get [-asqdyfmubV] [-o=config_string] [-c=config_file] [-t=target_release]
               [-a=architecture] {update | upgrade | dselect-upgrade | dist-upgrade |
               install pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  | remove pkg...  |
               purge pkg...  | source pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  |
               build-dep pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  |
               download pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  | check | clean |
               autoclean | autoremove | {-v | --version} | {-h | --help}}
```

The `-q` or `-qq` flag should go *before* the command, like so:

`apt-get -qq upgrade`

Comment: This is the correct answer! Any practical implementation needs to preserve prompts. Used correctly, `-q` absolutely works (no "animated" output) as well as `-qq` (no output except errors). Please upvote!

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Even with `-qq` before the install command I still get tons of junk everything from reading database to unpacking and setting up messages.

Comment: @CrazyCasta what command are you using?

Comment: Well, I've tried `sudo apt-get -qq -y install mercurial`, `sudo apt-get install -qq -y mercurial`, `sudo apt-get -qq install -qq -y mercurial` and other variations involving even more q's (though I don't see any documentation that suggests this would work. I'm running Debian Jessie on google cloud btw (8).  I've also tried Goetz's answer and it doesn't seem to work either. By doesn't seem to work I mean I don't notice a difference.

Comment: This works for me on Ubuntu 14.04 - are you sure that there hasn't been a change in behaviour for Debian Jessie? Does the `apt-get` manpage look like the above?

Comment: `-qq` doesn't wrok for me. `apt-get -qq install build-essential` still prints too much output. I'd like something like CentOS's `yum install -y -q $package`, which is totally silent and great to prevent noise in automation scripts.

Comment: in Ubuntu 16.04.1 the `-qq` option is entirely silent. There is zero output. What are you seeing and what exactly is the command you are using @StefanLasiewski?

Comment: This is Ubuntu 16.04.1, running as a Docker container. My guess is that the messages are actually from `dpkg`, which is called by `apt-get`. The command is `apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq upgrade && apt-get -qq install build-essential`. See https://gist.github.com/stefanlasiewski/be6776296e07e709e9d978d36c3681c5

Comment: Interesting @StefanLasiewski - I ran the Xenial docker image and ran your command exactly, but got a lot of output. Then I ran `apt-get -qq update` and it was silent...then `apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq upgrade` (still silent) and finally the full command which was silent. I scrubbed that container and started a new one and ran `apt-get -qq update` alone, followed by the full command. The update was silent, but the full command wasn't. Following the process I did before worked. This seems like a bug to me, this is all very unexpected but fairly deterministic.

Comment: In Docker you have 2 alternatives: (1) run each command separately rather than with `&&` joining them (might work, but it's not the "docker way") (2) redirect the output to /dev/null like in the other answer. Option 2 is probably your best bet while there is this bug.

Comment: @Mike: I noticed, that You are not running the same command as the OP - it was `install` and not `update` or `upgrade`. Those get silenced, but as in other posts, install uses `dpkg` underneath, which generates the output. This answer is not answering the original question.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `-qq` does not accomplish what OP wants, regardless of where or with which command it's used.

Comment: Same here: I tried putting the `-qq` before `install` as well as after `install`, and both scenarios still resulted in the `Unpacking ...`, `Selecting ...`, `Preparing ...`, etc. messages that I do not want to see. I am using the `ubuntu:20.04` Docker container

Answer (score 102):

We faced the same problem. `apt-get install -qq` removes most of the outputs but annoying "(Reading database ..." still persist.

We took a look in the source of apt and discover that the output is produced by dpkg that was forked by apt. Then the source of dpkg shows that the annoying soutput is only issued when isatty(1) is true. This is only the case when the fork uses pty instead pipe. Back to apt, there is a undocumented configuration variable that allows to use pipe instead pty which then solve the problem:

```
apt-get install -qq -o=Dpkg::Use-Pty=0 <packages>
```

Expecting that can help others.

Comment: Actually this is full correct answer. It's also allow to run apt-get with single -q and see *some* output and don't see annoying "Reading database"

Comment: @valodzka Which ubuntu version are you on? On CircleCI (with Ubuntu 14.04) it steall reads `(Reading database ... 625142 files and directories currently installed.)`.

Comment: I tested it on Debian 8

Comment: I tried this with Ubuntu 14.04 based Docker build and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I'm trying this on gcloud debian jessie (8) and I still get reading database lines and unpacking/setting up lines.

Comment: This works for me. If you aren't using -q or -qq then you still see the '(Reading database..' lines but they are put through pipe (like all the other output) instead of bypassing it. Perfect.

Comment: This answer might not be accepted, but it definitely deserves the most upvotes since it is really the only answer that works with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This answer does not work for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: There's still a bunch of Selecting/Preparing/Setting up lines...

Comment: The `-o=Dpkg::Use-Pty=0` worked perfect on Ubuntu 18.04. It only shows one "Reading database" instead of multiple ones with progress updates every 5%.

Comment: I can specifically report that `apt-get -o Dpkg::Use-Pty=0 install` (in that exact order) is acceptably quiet on Ubuntu 18.04. I don't want to know why there's all that machinery in there to use a pty in the first place; it must be pretty horrific…

Comment: It seems that `-o=Dpkg::Use-Pty=0` doesn't affect the output in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This is the correct answer! Works on ubuntu 20.04 where `-qq` and other `apt.conf` options do not

Comment: Adding `-o=Dpkg::Use-Pty=0` seems to have successfully suppressed the messages in `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, but I'm still getting the `Unpacking ...`, `Selecting ...`, `Preparing ...`, etc. messages. I'm using the `ubuntu:20.04` Docker container

Comment: Can that also be set via an environment variable or config file?

Answer (score 67):

A simple redirection could do this. It's not exactly what you had in mind, I'm sure, but it sure as hell works :)

In short, just whack `> /dev/null` on the end of any command where you want to redirect all the `stdout` into nothingness. Things outputted on `stderr` will still show in the console.

```
$ sudo apt-get update > /dev/null
[sudo] password for oli: 
$
```

No junk! And here's what happens if we're silly and break something:

```
$ apt-get cheese > /dev/null
E: Invalid operation cheese
$
```

Comment: That's a bit of a problem if you get a prompt...

Comment: If this is part a script, you wouldn't put a `sudo` in front of `apt-get`. You would just `sudo` when running the script instead.

Comment: @l0b0 Hmm, yeah it is. Don't really know how to suggest splitting out prompts other than knowing when to expect them (removals and unverified packages are the only ones in there IIRC). Or, add `-y` into the mix (with caution!)

Comment: The OP was fine with using -qq which implies -y. So adding a -y or just running his original apt-get upgrade -qq > /dev/null  give the same result

Comment: @Oli If you're absolutely sure you're not going to make your system catch on fire, you could always `sudo apt-get upgrade -qq --force-yes > /dev/null`. `-qq` implies `-y`, as WulfHart said, and `--force-yes` makes it plow through just about anything.

Comment: @Oli, as far as I understand, your solution redirects both stdout and stderr to /dev/null. Am I correct or am I missing something?

Comment: @Vorac No it's just redirecting `stdout` (seeing the errors is a desirable thing IMO).

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude The man page says "you should never use -qq without a no-action modifier...as APT may decided to do something you did not expect".

Comment: This is not the answer to the question; it's a workaround.

Answer (score 6):

As you can see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/972528) and [here](https://serverfault.com/a/227194/514993)
You can do:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -yq install [packagename]
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=dialog
```

Or one line:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq install [packagename]
```

Answer (score 3):

With `apt-get -qq install -y PACKAGE 2> /dev/null` you can:

1. Show only the errors with `-qq`.
2. Send the errors to `/dev/null` (not show) so with that you can install a package with zero output.

Comment: This is not what OP is asking. OP explicitly says they want errors to print, whereas this will hide errors

Answer (score 1):

For me this works perfectly for fully silent/zero output while installing cause NULL STDIN and STDOUT.

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -qq [packagename] < /dev/null > /dev/null
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score -1):

You can use a python script to do literally anything with the stdout and stderr of every command. For example, if you want to see a dynamic output including only the last line of the output, you can use the following script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess, sys
process = subprocess.Popen(sys.argv[1:], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while process.poll() is None:
  stdout = process.stdout.readline().decode()[:-1]
  print(stdout,end='\r')
print()
```

If you know how to work with strings in python, you can tweak the script to print only the lines you want to be printed, in whatever format you wish.

Save the above code in a file such as run.py. Then you can run any command to see only the last line of the output dynamically. For example:

```
./run.py sudo apt-get install <package>
```

or:

```
./run.py sudo apt-get update
```

> Note 1: Don't forget to give exec permission to your script:

```
chmod +x run.py
```

> Note 2: You can make a proper symlink for a more convenient usage (or alternatively add the script path to $PATH environment variable which I do not suggest):

```
sudo ln -s <path/to/yourscript.py> /usr/bin/run
```

Afterwards, you can only use:

```
run <command-with-desired-output-format>
```