# Can not write log (Is /dev/pts mounted?) - openpty in Ubuntu-on-Windows?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

What exactly does the error message beginning with E: mean? I assume it has to do with the file structure on Ubuntu-on-Windows, but what exactly?

```
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
      os-prober
    Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
    The following extra packages will be installed:
      libxslt1.1
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      libxslt1.1 xmlstarlet
    0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 435 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 1023 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libxslt1.1 amd64 1.1.28-2build1 [145 kB]
    Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe xmlstarlet amd64 1.5.0-1 [290 kB]
    Fetched 435 kB in 3s (134 kB/s)
    **E: Can not write log (Is /dev/pts mounted?) - openpty (2: No such file or directory)**
    Selecting previously unselected package libxslt1.1:amd64.
    (Reading database ... 28723 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../libxslt1.1_1.1.28-2build1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libxslt1.1:amd64 (1.1.28-2build1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package xmlstarlet.
    Preparing to unpack .../xmlstarlet_1.5.0-1_amd64.deb .
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that the Windows NT Linux Subsystem does not provide pseudo-terminals.  People get this same error in vanilla Ubuntu/Debian when installing packages in changed root environments where `/dev` hasn't been populated with the various pseudo-terminal devices.  In the Windows NT Linux Subsystem's case, they aren't there simply because the operating system kernel isn't supplying them.

The message actually comes from the `apt-get` command, which is invoking the `dpkg` command with its standard I/O attached to a pseudo-terminal.  [Here is the source code for where it happens](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/apt/trusty/view/head:/apt-pkg/deb/dpkgpm.cc#L1068).  (The message has changed slightly in Ubuntu 16.  The Windows NT Linux Subsystem uses an earlier version of Ubuntu by default, though.)

### Further reading

- [*LTSP error: Can not write log, openpty() failed (/dev/pts not mounted?)*](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ltsp/+bug/294403).  Ubuntu bug #294403.  Canonical.
- Anatoly Zaretsky (2016-03-31). [*Pseudoterminals*](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908/suggestions/13248360).  Windows Developer Feedback.  Microsoft corporation.
- [*termios implementation is incomplete*](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/169).  BashOnWindows bug #169.  2016-04-13.  Microsoft corporation.
- [*docker installation fails E: Can not write log(Is /dev/pts mounted?)*](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/85).  BashOnWindows bug #85.  2016-04-08.  Microsoft corporation.
- [*apt-get cannot write log, reports openpty error*](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/80).  BashOnWindows bug #80.  2016-04-08.  Microsoft corporation.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2000). [*Capturing console I/O in Win32*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/capture-console-win32.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11581935
- [How do I make apt-get install less noisy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258219/)