# DEBIAN_FRONTEND environment variable

Tags: apt, environment-variables

My potential hosting provider [suggests](https://billing.hostens.com/knowledgebase/article/125/make-minimal-os-on-kvm-based-server/) to run a command in the terminal in order to make KVM based server's OS image minimal. Since their KVM templates come with packages I will not need, I thought I might use that same command to remove unwanted packages.

That command starts with `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`, then invoke `apt-get remove` as follows:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get remove --purge -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" package-1 package-2 ... package-n; apt-get -y autoremove; apt-get clean all
```

It is the first time I encounter the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` environment variable, and I could not find useful information so far. So I wonder what setting it to `noninteractive` does, and if it is advisable, because I suppose that value (`noninteractive`) would persist.

Comment: Without knowing what it does, I can tell that when you set a variable that way as a part of a longer command string, it's only effective when running that command. It does not persist.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/227190/how-do-i-ask-apt-get-to-skip-any-interactive-post-install-configuration-steps

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Simply prepending an `apt` command with `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=something` does not persist after the single command to which it is applied.

The `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` options are documented in the Section 7 manual pages of `debconf` (you may need to install the `debconf-doc` package in order to make these available on your system). From `man 7 debconf`:

```
Frontends
   One of debconf's unique features is that the interface it  presents  to
   you is only one of many, that can be swapped in at will. There are many
   debconf frontends available:

   dialog The default frontend, this uses  the  whiptail(1)  or  dialog(1)
          programs to display questions to you. It works in text mode.

   readline
          The  most  traditional frontend, this looks quite similar to how
          Debian configuration always has been:  a  series  of  questions,
          printed  out  at  the console using plain text, and prompts done
          using the readline library. It even supports tab completion. The
          libterm-readline-gnu-perl package is strongly recommended if you
          chose to use this frontend; the default readline module does not
          support  prompting  with default values.  At the minimum, you'll
          need the perl-modules package installed to use this frontend.

          This frontend has some special hotkeys. Pageup (or ctrl-u)  will
          go  back  to  the previous question (if that is supported by the
          package that is using debconf), and pagedown  (or  ctrl-v)  will
          skip forward to the next question.

          This is the best frontend for remote admin work over a slow con‐
          nection, or for those who are comfortable with unix.

   noninteractive
          This is the anti-frontend. It never interacts with you  at  all,
          and  makes  the  default  answers  be used for all questions. It
          might mail error messages to root, but that's it;  otherwise  it
          is  completely  silent  and  unobtrusive, a perfect frontend for
          automatic installs. If you are using this front-end, and require
          non-default  answers  to questions, you will need to preseed the
          debconf database; see the section below  on  Unattended  Package
          Installation for more details.
```

It also notes that:

```
   You can change the default frontend debconf uses by reconfiguring  deb‐
   conf.  On the other hand, if you just want to change the frontend for a
   minute, you can set the DEBIAN_FRONTEND  environment  variable  to  the
   name of the frontend to use. For example:

     DEBIAN_FRONTEND=readline apt-get install slrn

   The  dpkg-reconfigure(8) and dpkg-preconfigure(8) commands also let you
   pass --frontend= to them, followed by the frontend  you  want  them  to
   use.

   Note  that not all frontends will work in all circumstances. If a fron‐
   tend fails to start up for some reason, debconf will print out  a  mes‐
   sage explaining why, and fall back to the next-most similar frontend.
```

Comment: I see `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` commonly used in Dockerfiles. This answer makes me wonder why we simply don't use the `--yes` flag with apt commands as it'll be more explicit and in most cases it'll meet our needs.

Comment: @Dennis I think it's because readline is not necessarily installed, and apt can output a warning as such.

Comment: Note: if using `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` with `sudo`, set the variable within the `sudo` command, and not for it.  That is: `sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install slrn`.  If  you put the env variable setting before `sudo`, it will be valid for the `sudo` command itself, and `sudo` will not copy it to the `apt-get` command being run.  Using it between `sudo` and the actual command is `sudo` syntax for setting up env variables for the command to be run (see man page).  This gave me a hard time, so I thought like sharing.

Comment: If you want to change the frontend default behavior to `noninteractive`, you can do that with the following command: `dpkg-reconfigure debconf --frontend=noninteractive`

Comment: @Dennis two remarks. As I understand it `apt` doesn't have a stable command line interface and therefore isn't recommended (for a Dockerfile/Containerfile), instead `apt-get` is. And the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` variable also affects some commands called under the hood, not just `apt`/`apt-get`. If you ever get warnings about a non-functional terminal, _this_ is how you can suppress them. On the other hand `--yes` won't change a thing for these cases.

Comment: Python also asks for input without DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737359/trying-to-create-a-custom-docker-image-but-getting-asked-for-question-during-a-r

Answer (score 15):

When writing unattended scripts (including Dockerfiles), when using `apt install -y` but **without** `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`, sometimes installation will get stuck at an interactive prompt.

[image]

By running the install command with `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` these interactive xprompts are disabled.