# How to trigger an alias over sshpass/ssh?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, sshpass

I have a server with an alias as follows:

```
~/.bash_aliases 
alias update='sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade'
```

Now I want to create a shortcut from my desktop that can simply trigger this script remotely over sshpass:
For a simple login, it works as follows:

`sshpass -p "<password>" ssh <user>@<host>`

But adding the alias as ssh command does not work and simply closes the terminal without action:

`sshpass -p "<password>" ssh <user>@<host> 'update'`

Question: is it possible at all?

Comment: ... `ssh -t user@localhost /bin/bash -ic 'update'`

Comment: @bac0n would you consider making this an answer (i.e. that alias expansion only occurs by default in an interactive shell, and sudo requires a tty)?

Answer (score 1):

In my first example, I made it easy by turning the bash session into an interactive shell, which sets the `expand_aliases` shopt_option. There is also a *case-statement* at the beginning of .bashrc that disallows *sourcing* .bashrc in non-interactive shells, which in turn, means your .bash_aliases won't be *sourced*. Furthermore,  even if `ssh` will interpret this as a non-interactive session, you may use the `-t` option to force a pseudo-terminal allocation for menus and screen-based applications to work.

```
ssh -t user@localhost '/bin/bash -ic update'
```

It can be accomplished in *non-interactive* shells, as well, but apt will still need a pseudo-terminal, though (can be solved by changing the frontend used by [apt](https://askubuntu.com/a/972528/986805) to a non-interactive choice).

```
ssh -t user@localhost '/bin/bash --init-file ~/.bash_aliases -O expand_aliases -c update'
```

Next is the use of `-p` passwords in sshpass that does not seem to die off. `sshpass` should never be used in this way, ever. I can't see a scenario where this is needed. First, it will end up in your `history`, i.e., of course, you don't have it turned off. It may also, in some circumstances, end up in the ps tree. **sshpass makes very little to hide the pass in this mode**. You should at least use the file option or `SSHPASS=`.

```
editor .ssh/passwd_credentials && chmod 400 $_
```

<sup>passwd_credentials should only contain the password.</sup>

And is used by the `-f` option.

```
sshpass -f ~/.ssh/passwd_credentials ssh user@localhost
```

You may also encapsulate your `ssh` command in a script file.

```
#!/bin/sh
SSHPASS='password' sshpass -e ssh user@localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sshpass` will not trigger the server to load the aliases, but you can pass the commands like this:

```
sshpass -p <password> ssh <user>@<host> sudo /usr/bin/apt update && sudo /usr/bin/apt -y upgrade
```

**HOWEVER** ... you're going to get a message like this:

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
```

Which means you'll need to do a *very* ugly thing to make the system do what you want:

```
sshpass -p <password> ssh <user>@<host> echo <password> | sudo /usr/bin/apt update && echo <password> | sudo /usr/bin/apt -y upgrade
```

This method is suboptimal for a number of reasons, but it will *technically* accomplish your goals. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, it may make sense to look at using `unattended-upgrades` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Would you favor `unattended-upgrades` over `apt-cron`?

Comment: If you don't plan on being "present" for the upgrade, then yes. Unattended upgrades will handle security and other critical updates automagically. Blindly firing a cron task off to servers will update *all* software, which can have consequences if you're not paying attention.