# Problem with xfce terminal during dialogs in command line installs

Tags: command-line, apt, dialog

I am using terminal in Ubuntu Studio 20.4.2. During installs with apt in the terminal, if there is a dialog that requires a keyboard or mouse response, the response is not recognized and the apt install hangs at the dialog. This has happened with two installs thus far when using the terminal for apt installations.

Comment: It's hard to guess the issue from your description - however if you are having difficulty with the default dialog based interface you can try setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=readline` to get a pure command line interface. See for example [DEBIAN_FRONTEND environment variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972516/debian-frontend-environment-variable)