# How to do apt upgrade with noninteractive?

Tags: apt, aptitude

I want make Ubuntu 18.04 server (text only) upgrade itself and keep original configure in a bash script.
I tried

```
apt update && apt upgrade -y
```

and

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dist-upgrade
```

and

```
apt upgrade --yes --force-yes
```

and

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" upgrade -q -y --force-yes
```

ALL not working which means they all ask for interactive.

Comment: "ALL not working", but what exactly is your output? Are you receiving any errors?  Might be something else that fails your attempts? Also as @sudodus asked - what version and flavor of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/972516/debian-frontend-environment-variable

Answer (score 5):

Finally I make a script that works.
This will try upgrade everything and keep the configuration file,
**Only safe for flash installed box.**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update -y
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo -E apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" dist-upgrade -q -y --allow-downgrades --allow-remove-essential --allow-change-held-packages
```